# Powershell Export-CSV Tab Delimiter Output issue

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-5.1

Below is the Input CSV file which when after doing a sort and doing an export-csv , the format of the out does not looks good when opened.

```
$FileLogdate = (Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss)

# Inputfile
"{0}`t{1}`t{2}" -f "COne","CTwo","CThree" | Out-File -Append $PSScriptRoot\testtrycsv_$FileLogdate.csv

"{0}`t{1}`t{2}" -f "C1R1","C2R1","C3R1" | Out-File -Append $PSScriptRoot\testtrycsv_$FileLogdate.csv
"{0}`t{1}`t{2}" -f "C1R1","C2R1","C3R1" | Out-File -Append $PSScriptRoot\testtrycsv_$FileLogdate.csv
"{0}`t{1}`t{2}" -f "C1R2","C2R2","C3R2" | Out-File -Append $PSScriptRoot\testtrycsv_$FileLogdate.csv
"{0}`t{1}`t{2}" -f "C1R1","C2R1","C3R1" | Out-File -Append $PSScriptRoot\testtrycsv_$FileLogdate.csv

# Output file
"{0}`t{1}`t{2}" -f "COne","CTwo","CThree" | Out-File -Append $PSScriptRoot\test-temp.csv

$input = "$PSScriptRoot\testtrycsv_$FileLogdate.csv"
$inputCsv = Import-Csv $input | Sort-Object * -Unique
$inputCsv | Export-Csv "$PSScriptRoot\test-temp.csv" -NoTypeInformation -delimiter "`t"
```

below is input csv file

[image: Input CSV File when opened]

Below is the output format of the export-csv view when opened

[image: Format of file after export-csv]

When looking the export-csv in Notepad++ , it looks like this

[image]

Comment: That's an Excel quirk. Excel uses its default setting when opening a CSV file and won't interpret all delimiters, thus if you don't use the one Excel like, it will put everything in the same cell. See : https://superuser.com/a/686415/409284

Comment: @SagePourpre - I updated the question with how the export-csv output looks like in Notepad++ . Any suggestion ?

Comment: The double quotes make it one field.  $input is a reserved word.

Comment: Watch out for out-file -append as well.  It doesn't check the current encoding of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually cannot reproduce the behaviour you're having.
Let's create your input data ...

```
$CSVInput = @'
"COne","CTwo","CThree" 
"C1R1","C2R1","C3R1"
"C1R1","C2R1","C3R1"
"C1R2","C2R2","C3R2"
"C1R1","C2R1","C3R1"
'@ | 
    ConvertFrom-Csv
```

When we output this input data it looks like this:

```
PS:>$CSVInput

COne CTwo CThree
---- ---- ------
C1R1 C2R1 C3R1  
C1R1 C2R1 C3R1  
C1R2 C2R2 C3R2  
C1R1 C2R1 C3R1
```

Now let's sort your input data ...

```
$SortedCSV =
    $CSVInput | 
        Sort-Object -Property * -Unique
```

When we output this sorted input data it looks like this:

```
PS:>$SortedCSV

COne CTwo CThree       
---- ---- ------       
C1R1 C2R1 C3R1
C1R2 C2R2 C3R2
```

Now let's export these sorted data to a file in the current working directory using a `<tab>` as delimiter ...

```
$SortedCSV |
    Export-Csv -Path '.\CSVOutput.csv' -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation
```

And the output of that looks like this ...

[image: CSV file opened in Notepad++]

`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Since, I did not wanted to have "" quotes, I had to add the following code                        
(Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\test-temp.csv) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '"', ''}|Out-File $PSScriptRoot\test-temp_2.csv

Comment: @Joe_12345 The quotes actually belong to the standard. You may try the [Export-Csv -UseQuotes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.3#-usequotes) of the PowerShell version 7.x where you have more control over the quoting.